# Gray Out Entire Row After Current Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Good Afternoon,

Been trying to get a conditional formatting to work so an entire row will be grayed out once it is past the current date. But the entire row is not changing, not sure if I am missing something or it cant override other formatting rules?

Plus, I have a script going for when the page opens, it puts the cursor on the current date, not sure if I have that set up properly too. Wondering if someone could help me out.

THANK YOU!!

Plus, I have attached a copy of the sheet as an example.

:)

[SHEET EXAMPLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1njzflpoCTV4HgLU6ScD1RTDjyg-rNHBOtcEmgKjWBYY/edit#gid=1357230574)

Comment: Change permission for the sheet, so that everyone who has the link can view it. 
It is possible to do it with conditional formatting. You should remember that you need to arrange all formatting rules from most important to less important. You will not see the effect if this rule will be under other rules.

Answer (score 0):

#### With a Script

Assume date is in first column

```
function greyout() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const tdv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(new Date(r[0]).valueOf() < tdv) {
      sh.getRange(i + 1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground("gray");
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the dates are in column B

Comment: Change r[0] to r[1]

Comment: Thank you, however seems to only change the first row?

Comment: Please post your code and provide a screen shot of your sheet

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here is the code....

function greyout() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const tdv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(new Date(r[1]).valueOf() < tdv) {
      sh.getRange(i + 1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground("gray");
    }
  })
}

Comment: Please post it into your question and format this way [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)